# Scrapy scrapes one page 'n' times but other single time when in a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scraper

I am scraping two pages for a single id iteratively. First scraper works for all id's but the second one works for only one id.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "scraper"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  start_urls = ['http://example.com/viewData']

  def parse(self, response):
    ids = ['1', '2', '3']

    for id in ids:
      # The following method scraps for all id's
      yield scrapy.Form.Request.from_response(response,
                                                   ...
                                              callback=self.parse1)

      # The following method scrapes only for 1st id
      yield Request(url="http://example.com/viewSomeOtherData",
                    callback=self.intermediateMethod)

  def parse1(self, response):
    # Data scraped here using selectors

  def intermediateMethod(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                ...
                                           callback=self.parse2)

  def parse2(self, response):
    # Some other data scraped here
```

I want to scrap two different pages for a single id.

Comment: Scrapy has  a duplicate URL filter, it's possible this is filtering your Request . Try adding `dont_filter = True` afer the `callback=`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding dont_filter solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the following line:

```
yield Request(url="http://example.com/viewSomeOtherData",
              callback=self.intermediateMethod)
```

to:

```
yield Request(url="http://example.com/viewSomeOtherData",
              callback=self.intermediateMethod,
              dont_filter=True)
```

worked for me.

Scrapy has a duplicate URL filter, it's possible this is filtering your Request. Try adding dont_filter = True afer the callback as suggested by Steve.